# How to convert toFixed(2) in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, decimalformat, tofixed

What should I write in the place of `area.toFixed(2)`

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = 20
    val h = 30
    val area = a * h / 2
    println("Triangle area = ${area.toFixed(2)}")
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code editing service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you really meet a problem that how to convert Javascript code to Kotlin code. You need to ask the question clearly at next time, :). you can use `String#format` instead, for example:

```
println("%.2f".format(1.0))  // print "1.00"

println("%.2f".format(1.253))  // print "1.25"

println("%.2f".format(1.255))  // print "1.26"
```

**AND** the `area` is an `Int` which means it will truncates the *precision*, Kotlin doesn't like as Javascript use the numeric by default, so you should let *`a*h`* divide by a `Double`, then your code is like as below:

```
//                  v--- use a `Double` instead
val area = a * h / 2.0

println("Triangle area = ${"%.2f".format(area)}")
```

Comment: The last question. How to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit?
Input: 25; 0; -5.5; 32.3
Output: 77; 32; 22.1; 90.14
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val celsius = 25
    val fahrenheit = celsius * 1.8 + 32
    println(fahrenheit)
}

Comment: @student your code is right. what's wrong of the code?

Comment: In the first case it should be 77, not 77.0 or 77.00.

Comment: @student use formatter instead: `DecimalFormat().apply { roundingMode = HALF_UP; maximumFractionDigits = 2 }`

Comment: @student Kotlin is base on Java, if you want to mastering Kotlin you should learning [tag:java] first.

Comment: @holi-java Not anymore, Kotlin is now multi-platform. And your answer doesn't work with Javascript target.

Comment: @PointerNull thanks for your feedback, but the original OP want to implement the javascript like function target in jvm only, not target for all platforms.